# How to remove border from bootstrap's dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, border

I copied and pasted a dropdown menu from bootstrap and started messing around with it. I first copied the one where the dropdown is a button, then I changed it to the one with anchor tags. When I changed it from button to anchor, these borders just appeared and I can't get them to go away. I tried just about everything.

[image: sample]

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-center pb-3 px-md-4 mb-0 bg-white border-bottom box-shadow">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Crabs')" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle ml-3 mr-3 navbartext" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="gotoDetail('cr01')">Medium Soft Shell Crabs</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="gotoDetail('cr02')">Hotel Soft Shell Crabs</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="gotoDetail('cr03')">Prime Soft Shell Crabs</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="gotoDetail('cr04')">Jumbo Soft Shell Crabs</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="gotoDetail('cr05')">Whale Soft Shell Crabs</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="gotoDetail('cr06')">Crab Meat</a>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>


#dropdownMenu2 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #4d4d4d;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

/* Removes caret from dropdown menu button */
.dropdown-toggle::after{
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
    display: inherit;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I rendered your code on Codepen.

Looks like you just need to remove the class `.border-bottom` from the parent div.

That should do it.

Comment: I just noticed I have the other border in the picture. I just want to be clear that i’m referring to the borders around the links.

Comment: Oh, you can just remove that attribute on the Link button called `type="button"`. That attribute adds `-webkit-appearance: button` to your code which has those borders as a default. @Survolt1034

Comment: You have to remove / override `webkit-appearance: button;` AND `border-color` from the css class `.btn-secondary`. Learn opening developer tool by pressing F12 and just play around there.

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 4 your can simply remove the `btn` css class. Then the whole thing will behave like a regular link. The hover effect of the link can also be annoying, that's why I added this here to my css files:

```css
.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

That shuts off the hover effect for the link element.